# i am facing issue while generating apk in react-native after implementing react-native-code-push

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

i am using react-native version : "react-native": "0.68.1"

and "react-native-code-push": "^8.0.2",

i doing all the setup i am trying to build first apk using this command npx react-native run-android --variant=release ia m getting this error

```
node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), grep(), grep()

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCnRJ.png)

after removing `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"`

from build.gradle file and moving to codepush.gradle it works fine , but its does nt update the app successfull appcenter release.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `./gradlew clean --stacktrace --info` inside android directory. As I was facing the same issue with `"react-native-code-push": "^8.0.2"` but after downgrading to `^7.0.0` it got resolved.